# Export html content to pdf using JasperReports

Tags: html, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

How do I export HTML content into PDF using `JasperReports`, I have a parameter which carries value of the type HTML, and I have to export the same to a pdf file, where the pdf has to parse the html content

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777342/pdf-file-generation-from-xml-or-html

Answer (score 12):

For showing *html* code in report we can use *htmlcomponent* developed by Jaspersoft (as I understnd after looking at source code the author is Narcis Marcu).

This component has a lot of limitations and cannot assist you in every case for any html page of any complexity. Anyway, the below is explains how to use this component.

This component can be easily added to the report with help of *iReport 5.6.0*. At last versions of *Jaspersoft Studio* (*JSS*) this component was removed from the palette for some reasons.

#### The *Html* component in *iReport*:

[image: Html component in iReport]

#### Using JSS

If you are using the *JSS* there is no reason to be upset - the support of *Html* component is still present in *Studio*. You can find the *htmlcomponent.jar* in folder like this: `Jaspersoft Studio-6.3.1.final\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\38\0\.cp\lib\`.

We can use *Generic* component in *JSS* for using all functionality of *Html* component.

[image: How to add Generic component in JSS]

For doing this we should set at least couple properties of *Generic* component:

[image: Properties of Generic component]

*Generic Type Name* should be: ***`htmlelement`***
*Generic Type Namespace* should be: ***`http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/html`***

We can operate with this properties of *Html* component:

- **scaleType** - Image displaying type. Supports one of this values: *Clip, FillFrame, RetainShape, RealHeight, RealSize*
- **horizontalAlign** - Horizontal image alignment. Supports one of this values: *Left, Center, Right*
- **verticalAlign** - Vertical image alignment. Supports one of this values: *Top, Middle, Bottom*
- **clipOnOverflow**
- **evaluationTime**
- **evaluationGroup**

It *JSS* this properties can be set with help of *Advanced* tab of component's Properties:

[image: Setting properties in JSS]

At *iReport* its much easier to set the same properties:

[image: Setting properties in iReport]

As I mentioned before the *JSS* still has the *htmlcomponent* support. If you have *jrxml* file with *htmlcomponent* you can see all properties in *JSS* in the same way as at *iReport*.

[image: Setting properties in JSS for template with htmlcomponent]

### Sample of using htmlcomponent component

We can show this simple *html* page at *pdf* report with help of *JRPdfExporter*.

The *html* page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample of html based report</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-left: 11em;
            font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
            Times, serif;
            color: purple;
            background-color: #a5d8da
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, Arial,
            SunSans-Regular, sans-serif
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>This is a sample of html based report</h1>

<p>Only minimal html features are supported</p>

<p>At least images are supported</p>
<br/><br/>

<img src='file://C:\images\smile.png' alt='Smile' height='100' width='100'>
</body>
</html>
```

We will try to use *htmlcomponent* with help of *wrapper* (native component) for *HTML component* and with help of *Generic* component.

The *html* code will be passed via report's parameter (`htmlCode` in samples)

#### Using native *htmlcomponent* component.

The *jrxml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Html component" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="htmlCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="742">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="742"/>
                <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="RetainShape" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Top">
                    <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA[$P{htmlCode}]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
                </hc:html>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Using *Generic* component.

The *jrxml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Generic builds html" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="htmlCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="742">
            <genericElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="742"/>
                <genericElementType namespace="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/html" name="htmlelement"/>
                <genericElementParameter name="htmlContent">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$P{htmlCode}]]></valueExpression>
                </genericElementParameter>
                <genericElementParameter name="scaleType">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA["RetainShape"]]></valueExpression>
                </genericElementParameter>
                <genericElementParameter name="verticalAlign">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA["Top"]]></valueExpression>
                </genericElementParameter>
                <genericElementParameter name="horizontalAlign">
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA["Left"]]></valueExpression>
                </genericElementParameter>
            </genericElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

In both cases we can use the same *Java* code:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("htmlCode", "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\">\n" +
        "<html>\n" +
        "<head>\n" +
        "    <title>Sample of html based report</title>\n" +
        "    <style type=\"text/css\">\n" +
        "        body {\n" +
        "            padding-left: 11em;\n" +
        "            font-family: Georgia, \"Times New Roman\",\n" +
        "            Times, serif;\n" +
        "            color: purple;\n" +
        "            background-color: #a5d8da\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "\n" +
        "        h1 {\n" +
        "            font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, Arial,\n" +
        "            SunSans-Regular, sans-serif\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "    </style>\n" +
        "</head>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "<body>\n" +
        "<h1>This is a sample of html based report</h1>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "<p>Only minimal html features are supported</p>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "<p>At least images are supported</p>\n" +
        "<br/><br/>\n" +
        "<img src='file:/C:\\images\\smile.png' alt='Smile' height='100' width='100'>\n" +
        "</body>\n" +
        "</html>");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

**For valid working (report compiling) we should add *htmlcomponent.jar* to the classpath!**

#### Output result

The output result for both cases will be the same:

[image: The pdf file generated with JRPdfExporter]

---

More info:

- Information about using Generic Element - [JasperReports - Generic Element Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/genericelement/index.html#genericelements)
- Nice answer by Petter Friberg: [How to export HTML text with embedded images (base64, data uri) using the htmlcomponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41023179/876298)
- The source code of *htmlcomponent* component and the sample of using can be found in *JasperReports library* package at `jasperreports-6.x\demo\samples\htmlcomponent` folder
- Another sample can be found at another folder of *JasperReports library* package - `jasperreports-6.x\demo\samples\genericelement`

Comment: i dont understand if the use of **generic component** require also the htmlcomponent.jar

Comment: jar path for Jaspersoft Studio plugin 6.3.2 in Eclipse Neon is different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50585704/1915920

Comment: I'm getting `No generic element handlers found for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/html` :(

Comment: created a pdf using this code; html portion in pdf has a background blue color, which doesn't seem to go away; any idea why color is there & how to fix?

Comment: I hv not used exactly "this" code, I hv my own html which works fine in itext; when I added my html(which doesn't have any color) in above code, pdf shows dark blue color in background