# PDF file generation from XML or HTML

Tags: java, html, xml, pdf, itext

Are there any API/solution to generate PDF report from XML file data and definition.
For example the XML definition/data could be:

```
<pdf>
    <paragraph font="Arial">Title of report</paragraph>
</pdf>
```

Converting HTML to PDF will be also a good solution I feel.

Currently we write Java code using iText API. I want to externalize the code so that non-technical person can edit and make changes.

Comment: About "CSS+XHTML to PDF" technologies, see [Why use XSL-FO instead of CSS2, for transform HTML into good PDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10641667/287948)
question and answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/). Use an XSLT stylesheet to convert the XML (or XHTML) into XSL-FO. Then use FOP to read the XSL-FO document and format it to a PDF document (see [Hello World with FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/quickstartguide.html#hello-world)).

Apache FOP can use a lot of memory for large documents (e.g., a 200-page PDF), which may require tweaking the [JVM memory settings](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/running.html#memory).

Comment: Please see my answer for a suggestion for "an XSLT style sheet".

Answer (score 4):

[iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) has a facility for generating PDFs from XML (and HTML, I think). [Here is the DTD](http://itext.sourceforge.net/itext.dtd), but I found it difficult to sort out. Aside from that, I never found any good documentation on what is supported. My approach was to look at the source for [SAXiTextHandler](http://kickjava.com/src/com/lowagie/text/xml/SAXiTextHandler.java.htm) and [ElementTags](http://kickjava.com/src/com/lowagie/text/ElementTags.java.htm) to figure out what was acceptable. Although not ideal, it is pretty straight-forward.

```
<itext orientation="portrait" pagesize="LETTER" top="36" bottom="36" left="36" right="36" title="My Example" subject="My Subject" author="Me">
<paragraph size="8" >This is an example</paragraph>
</itext>

...

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.lowagie.text.xml.SAXiTextHandler;

...

String inXml = ""; //use xml above as an example
ByteArrayOutputStream temp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = null;
try
{
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, temp);
    SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
    parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(inXml), new SAXiTextHandler(document));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // instead, catch the proper exception and do something meaningful
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    if (writer != null)
    {
        try
        {
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ignore)
        {
            // ignore
        }
    } // if
}

//temp holds the PDF
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?projectname=jasperreports), it uses iText to export files i think, and its IDE is simple and can be used by non-programmers.

Edit: i forgot to mention, you can use JasperReports engine directly in your application, or you can use [iReport "Designer for JasperReports"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/files/)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a well supported XML format for this, as it will allow you to leverage the work of others.

A well supported XML format is DocBook XML - http://www.docbook.org/ - and this - http://sagehill.net/docbookxsl/index.html - appears to be a good resource on doing the XML -> PDF using XSLT with the Docbook style sheets and other formats.

This approach allows you to use any XSLT processor and any XSL/FO processor to get to your result.  This gives you easy scriptability as well as the freedom to switch implementations if needed - notably older Apache FOP implementations degraded badly when the resulting PDF got "too large".

Answer (score 0):

[Prince](http://www.princexml.com/) is one of the best tools out there.  It uses CSS for styles, so if you appreciate that method of separating data from display (read: your users are able to do that too), it may be a very good fit for you.  (The control over display that browsers offer through CSS is, by comparision, primitive.)