# JasperReports Server: HTML Component issue

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report with HTML component in *JasperReports 5.1*.

Its working fine in *iReport* but not working in *JasperReports Server Professional 5.0*.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found     starting with element 'hc:html'. 
One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":component}' is expected.
```

I tried to add the following properties in *JasperReports.properties* file but it didn't work:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.htmlelement=net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.HtmlElementExtensionsRegistryFactory

net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.htmlcomponent=net.sf.jasperreports.components.html.HtmlComponentExtensionsRegistryFactory
```

Please suggest how can I fix this.

Answer (score 3):

One of my colleague suggested the soluntion and it worked.

copy

```
 jasperreports-htmlcomponent-5.0.1.jar from <JaspersoftiReport-5.1.0>\ireport\modules\ext
```

paste to

```
 Web-Inf\lib  folder of jasperserver
```

Thanks

Ankush

Comment: Yes, I can confirm copying the library to jesper server does solved the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

for jasper *reports server 6.3.0.final* we put the `eclipse/plugins/com.jaspersoft.studio.html_6.3.2.final.jar!lib/htmlcomponent.jar` (*Eclipse Neon*) into `...\jasperreports-server-cp-6.3.0\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\lib`, restarted it and it worked :)