# How to increase the size of bullet points in report?

Tags: html, jasper-reports

I would like to increase the bullet size but not the text in iReport. I have tried using `html` markup and using the style attribute in the `<li>` tag. However, it doesn't change the size of the bullets.

The changing of font's size did not solve the issue.

Is there any other way that I can do to increase the size of the bullets?

In the expression editor:

```
//Other text above...
<ul>
<li style=\"font-size:15px;\">
<span style=\"font-size:10px;\">Sample Text 1</span>
</li>

<li>
<span style=\"font-size:10px;\">Sample Text 2</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: post some code , what have you tried till now ?

Comment: @MukeshRam i have tried using span as well but still the bullet points did not increase at all...

Comment: Try to change font's size

Comment: I think `jasper-reports` has its own template for it. not in html format.

Comment: @AlexK i have tried changing the font size using the style attribute...but only my text changes size, not the bullet points

Comment: Maybe this approach help you: [Export html content to pdf using JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1091760/876298). Don't use the complex style. Please give some feedback, because your case is very interesting