# How to add the HtmlComponent to JasperDesign

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I managed to add the `HtmlComponent` to my project through various searches.

My next problem is that I don't have a clue how to add it to a `JasperDesign`.
I simply can't find any way to add my `HtmlComponent` to a `JasperDesign` (not even through a group etc).

I use Jasper 5.6.1 and managed to get the HtmlComponent jar (5.0.1) out of the iReport tool (5.6.0).

My end purpose is to be able to have an HTML-table inside my report. I know it's not possible in any way, but perhaps, an HTML-component would be the most interesting thing. This way, an image of the table would be in my report, which is ok.

*This is my current code*

```
private JasperDesign getTable(String html, JasperDesign jasperDesign) {
        HtmlComponent table = new HtmlComponent();
        JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();
        expression.setText(html.replace("\n", ""));
        table.setHtmlContentExpression(expression);
        JRDesignGroup group = new JRDesignGroup();
        group.setName(TABLE_GROUP_PREFIX);
        JRDesignBand groupHeader = new JRDesignBand();
        groupHeader.setHeight(200);
        groupHeader.setSplitType(SplitTypeEnum.IMMEDIATE);
        groupHeader.addElement(table);
        ((JRDesignSection)  group.getGroupHeaderSection()).addBand(groupHeader);

       return jasperDesign;
}
```

The line `groupHeader.addElement(table)` fails because HtmlComponent is not an Element, but a Component.

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire You can look at [Export html content to pdf using JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1091760/876298) post

Comment: @AlexK, I can not use the link provided since my report is generated dynamically. I have no clue how many tables will in be my report in advance. It might be 0, it might be 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a component to the `JRDesign` you need to wrap it in the [`JRDesignComponentElement`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignComponentElement.html)

```
JRDesignComponentElement ce = new JRDesignComponentElement(design);
ce.setComponentKey(new ComponentKey("http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent", "hc", "html"));
ce.setComponent(table);
```

## Full example

```
//Create the design
JasperDesign design = new JasperDesign();
design.setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataTypeEnum.ALL_SECTIONS_NO_DETAIL); //We will run with no data
design.setName("Html test");
//Add a title band
JRDesignBand title = new JRDesignBand();
title.setHeight(100);
design.setTitle(title);

//Create our component
HtmlComponent hc = new HtmlComponent();
JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();
expression.setText("\"<b>Hello</b> world\"");
hc.setHtmlContentExpression(expression);

//Wrap it in a design componenent
JRDesignComponentElement ce = new JRDesignComponentElement(design);
ce.setComponentKey(new ComponentKey("http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent", "hc", "html"));
ce.setComponent(hc);
ce.setHeight(100);
ce.setWidth(100);
title.addElement(ce);

//Compile the design
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);

//Generate the print (passing no datasource, empty)
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String,Object>());

//Export to pdf
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter(); 
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("pdf/htmlComponent.pdf"));
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

## Output

[image: result]

<sup>Tons of code for a Hello world, it's often quicker to do the report in jrxml</sup>

Comment: Absolutely what I was looking for. Thank you so much! Now I can start fiddling around :).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you should minify the HTML and replace all " with \" and surround the end result in double quotes (""). Example: 
`"<table><tr><td style=\"border:1pt solid black;\"></td></tr></table>"`